# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'details.date.getTime')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im using https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification to be able to show notifications, in my case im using schedulednotifications with datetimepicker. I've used this before in an another project and it was working fine with no error, but in this project im getting TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'details.date.getTime') this error comes up after i pressed confirm after setting up the time etc.

```
notifSchedule = (todo, date) => {
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
  id: todo.id,
  message: todo.title,
  date,
  allowWhileIdle: true,
  priority: 'high',
});
};
```

this is exactly what ive been doing in the other project so it should work. the only thing different is im using class component right now and in the other project is functions only.

when i use date: new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 1000), // in 60 secs instead of date, it doesnt even fire anything nothing happens.

EDIT2:
full error message

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 3):
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'details.date.getTime')
localNotificationSchedule@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:129002:38
notifSchedule
handleChange@http://10.0./index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:129538:16
resolve@http://10.81/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:129662:19
tryCallOne@http://181/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27056:16
http://10.81/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27157:27
_callTimer@http://881/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30596:17
_callImmediatesPass@http://10.081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30635:17
callImmediates@http://1081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30852:33
__callImmediates@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2736:35
http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2522:34
__guard@http://1801/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2719:15
flushedQueue@http://1081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2521:21
flushedQueue@[native code]
invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

Comment: I think I could be ` date: new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 1000), // in 60 secs` here, could you test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself (todo, date) by removing todo and only having (date) worked,

Answer (score 0):

the passed in `date` param is probably undefined. debug what is exactly passed to `localNotificationSchedule`, it can be caused by some mistake you made with the component's lifecycle

Comment: no date is not underfined. when hovering the mouse over it it says (parameter) date: any. when going over the other project that has function components it says the same but it works on that projects

Answer (score 0):

As you are stating that you are using class based components so I want to add that please make sure that you binds the functions properly else it will not work. Class based functions needs binding of functions where functional do it by themselves. Sometimes values maybe seems to be undefined because you are not approaching them correctly.
**OR**
Debug the details from which you are extracting date or do like this

```
console.log(details); //if undefined do some action to fill it

details && details.date.getTime; //for conditional rendering
```

Comment: "Class based functions needs binding of functions where functional do it by themselves" thats prob the reason why it doesnt work i dont have any binds nor any state that has something to do with date

Comment: @iLightFPS you have to give the extra detail of code to pinpoint the real problem. Because here we just have to view the function you provided.

Comment: updated the code, and my state = {} only has todoId and newTodo init

Comment: Debug the details from which you are extracting date or do like this: 
"details && details.date.getTime"

Comment: updated the code again with full error message. nothing is working for me right now tried most things with no success

Comment: Check the structure of the details object that it contains the things you are accessing.

Comment: damn date wasnt even the problem todo was the problem once i removed it and only date was in (date) it worked

Comment: Check this link if get any help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42221015/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-props-date-getfullyear

Comment: @iLightFPS that's great. Happy for you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221959/discussion-between-suleman-ahmad-and-ilightfps).

Answer (score 0):

make sure your date is formatted as per required by the function, then use: `date: date`

```
notifSchedule = (todo, date) => {
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
  id: todo.id,
  message: todo.title,
  date: date,
  allowWhileIdle: true,
  priority: 'high',
});
};
```